# Как верно расставить знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, сложное-предложение

Скажите, пожалуйста, как пунктуационно верно написать такое предложение?

**Хотите пить, – пейте, не хотите, – не стоит себя заставлять.**

Или здесь не нужны тире?

Comment: Здесь не нужны запятые перед тире.

Comment: Простите, а вы уверены? Вы специалист по русскому языку?)

Comment: Нет, Сандро, я просто любитель.)

Comment: Но Вы ответили верно. Поэтому спасибо Вам!)

Answer (score 1):

**Полное** предложение могло бы выглядеть так:
Если хотите пить, то пейте, если не хотите пить, то не стоит себя заставлять.

В **неполных** предложениях, являющихся частью сложного предложения, на месте пропущенных членов или их частей ставится тире (если в месте пропуска делается пауза).

В первой части предложения пропущен союз **если... то**, имеются глаголы разных наклонений (то есть пауза присутствует). Ставим тире, которое поглощает запятую.
Во второй части предложения и союз пропущен, и пропущена часть сказуемого (*пить*), которая восстанавливается из предыдущей фразы. Тем более ставим тире, запятую — нет.

**Хотите пить — пейте, не хотите — не стоит себя заставлять.**

Если ты хочешь убить нас за это ― убей, мы будем знать, что погибли, защищая будущее, жизнь наших родов. [Герман Садулаев. Шалинский рейд (2009) // «Знамя», 2010]

Хочешь иметь ― отдай. Хочешь знать ― забудь. Хочешь убить врага ― возлюби его. [Елена Хаецкая. Мракобес/ Дорога (1997)]

[Тире в неполном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=91#pp91) (Розенталь)

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
«Хотите пить – пейте, не хотите – не стоит себя заставлять».
```

Причина тире - пропуск «тогда» или «в таком случае».

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, Азиза!

Answer (score 0):

Два тире (без запятой) ставятся здесь по другому правилу.

Розенталь:
Перед второй частью бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится тире, если в первой части обозначается условие совершения действия, о котором говорится во второй части (**в начале первой части можно добавить союз "если"**):
*Любишь кататься — люби и саночки возить.

Взялся за гуж — не говори, что не дюж.

На глаз поверишь — криво отмеришь*
http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=311 (пункт 5)